# What is the performance difference between accessing a global table value vs accessing a global variable in Lua?

Tags: lua

Let's say you have:

```
someNumber = 30
someTable = { someSubTable = { someNumber = 30 } }
```

Is there a significant performance different between how these variables are accessed and modified?

```
someNumber = 31
someTable.someSubTable.someNumber = 31
```

Comment: Each indexing a table with a string is expensive,

Answer (score 3):

Of course indexing into a two dimensional table comes at a cost. But ususally that's nothing you should think about. There are very few cases where this difference should matter to you. premature optimization is a considered a big no-no.

I ran a simple benchmark, calling a function that does the assignment 100 million times. Relative execution speed:

- assigning to global x: **1**
- assinging to global t.t.x: **1.08**
- assigning to global t[1][1]: **1.09**